# Why is Sequelize's save() not saving the changes that I've pushed to the JSON but saving everything else?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm making a function which will save the messages of my chat app to the database. It looks a bit like this:

```
let Server = require('../models/Server')

module.exports.sendMessage = (req, res, next) => {
    let serverRoom = req.body.serverRoom
    let serverId = req.body.server.id
    let server = Server.findByPk(serverId).then(result => {
        console.log(result.rooms[serverRoom].history)
        result.rooms[serverRoom].history.push('Hi')
        result.name = 'Test1'
        console.log(result.rooms[serverRoom].history)
        result.save();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })

    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Success'
    })
}
```

The server has a JSON column which contains an array of objects which have a history property which is an empty array. In my code, I console.log() the history of room with index of 0, then I push a message 'Hi' to the history of that room and then I console.log() the history again to check if the message was pushed. The console.logs prove that the message was indeed pushed, however, when I try to save() the object to the database, the JSON changes do not save.

However, the name of the result which I also change to 'Test1' in the code actually changes in the database, so the save() function is working but without saving the JSON changes. Any clue why is that happening?

Comment: Ciao, but with sequlize if you want to modify a record don't you have to use result.update(...) ?

Comment: Could you please write the version of sequlize you're using?

Also, i think MySQL's JSON datatype is not supported in Sequlize as per this issue: 

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4727

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in this line:

```
result.rooms[serverRoom].history.push('Hi');
```

You have to do explicitly set json objects and any array of json objects via using `concat` for example.

More info here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html#-code-model-changed----code-

Comment: keep in mind, that it neither will work for a deeply nested object change, you'll need a _.cloneDeep or a similar way to make a deep copy (not {...originalObject})